# How to use Banned API analyzers in own code

Tags: c#, roslyn

Roslyn has banned analyzers feature. I wanna use in my own code that compile code dynamically (own scripting engine based on C# lang) via CSharpCompilation class with WithAnalyzers extension method. I tried add package reference on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers but the package cannot use as a regular nuget package. Class CSharpSymbolIsBannedAnalyzer marked as unknown.

My code is like:

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(/* made syntax tree + dll refs */);

var analyzers = ImmutableArray.Create<DiagnosticAnalyzer>(
    new CSharpSymbolIsBannedAnalyzer()); // <- unknown type

var compilationWithAnalyzers = compilation.WithAnalyzers(
    analyzers,
    new AnalyzerOptions(ImmutableArray.Create<AdditionalText>(new BannedSymbolsAdditionalText(@"T:System.Diagnostics.Process;Don't use Process"))),
    cancellationToken);
```

But while I try to compile - CSharpSymbolIsBannedAnalyzer is unknown type.

Answer (score 4):

To use the Banned API analyzers in your own project, you don't need to use the analyzer in code, you just add a NuGet package reference:

1. Add a reference to the NuGet package to you project(s):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers" Version="3.3.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. Add a `BannedSymbols.txt` file to the compilation for your projects:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)BannedSymbols.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3. Populate your `BannedSymbols.txt` file with the APIs you want to ban and why, for example:

```
P:System.DateTime.Now; Use System.DateTime.UtcNow instead.
M:System.DateTimeOffset.op_Implicit(System.DateTime); Do not implicitly cast DateTime to DateTimeOffset.
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am create own scripting engine based on C# lang. And I wanna put some banned API for warning uses.